# Cannot resolve com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment

Tags: intellij-idea, guava, caliper

I git clone souce code from code.google.com
when i set guava-tests module benchmark as maven source root ,but it's also error
how to solve it?
see the picture 
**follow Frank advice I change to bechmark maked as a "Test Source Root"

but the Idea dislplay can't resolve symbol BeforeExperiment,but my .m2/repository
has the jar .see the first screenshot**.
[image]
[image]
[image]

when i exec  ,the result is below ,it is empty.

```
caliper  jar tf 1.0-beta-1/caliper-1.0-beta-1.jar|grep -E com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment |sort
caliper  jar tf 0.5-rc1/caliper-0.5-rc1.jar|grep -E com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment |sort
caliper  jar tf 1.0-beta-1/caliper-1.0-beta-1.jar|grep -E com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment |sort
```

Comment: Post the complete and exact error message, as text. I can't even see what error you're talking about in your picture.

Comment: In the second screenshot, the root package (`com`) has a blue folder icon which means you have set it as a "Source Root", when its parent folder (`benchmark`) is already set (correctly) as a "Source Root". Right-click on `com`, "Mark Directory As" / "Unmark as Source Root".

Comment: Actually, `benchmark` should be marked as a "Test Source Root", not a "Source Root".

Comment: @FrankPavageau I change to bechmark maked as a  "Test Source Root"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `guava-tests/benchmark` directory is currently not set as a source root in the Maven configuration because it won't build. That said, we just need to push a new version of Caliper to Maven Central that includes the new annotations and such, and I think that should be happening sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

No publicly available version of Caliper contains the `com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment` class.

You can compare the result of the following class searches on search.maven.org for yourself:

- [`com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment%22)
- [`com.google.caliper.Benchmark`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22com.google.caliper.Benchmark%22)

You can also check what's in your jar:

```
$ jar tf ~/.m2/repository/com/google/caliper/caliper/0.5-rc1/caliper-0.5-rc1.jar | \
    grep -E com.google.caliper.B | sort
com/google/caliper/Benchmark.class
$
```

Or using the most recent "release" of Caliper:

```
$ jar tf caliper-1.0-beta-1.jar | grep -E com.google.caliper.B | sort
com/google/caliper/Benchmark.class
$
```

Comment: when i exec the shell.can't find BeforeExperiment.how solve it

Comment: That's my point: _you can't_. Google has not released a version of Caliper with that class, the benchmarks are used internally and cannot be built with the publicly available tools & libs.

Comment: That's not exactly true.... it's in no release, but it's in the git repository already: commit 439ca07, 2013-06-21.

Comment: @maaartinus my bad, I didn't check the available code for Caliper. I think the step-by-step answer to set up the necessary environment (with local modifications to Guava's pom.xml) is a bit out of the SO scope, though...

Comment: No idea how to do it with Maven, etc.; this might get complicated.  In Eclipse I simply created a separate project and added it to Java Build Path.

Comment: @maaartinus would you give me the  git repository.Thanks!

Comment: @fuyou001: I can't, as it's not mine. :D But it's free: `git clone https://code.google.com/p/caliper/`, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/source/checkout).